# Bucket4J enable or disable dynamically

Tags: java, rate-limiting, bucket, bucket4j

I know than a rate limiter with Bucket4J  can be reconfigured dynamically,  but can it be dinamically enabled/disabled ?

In my case, if the configurations is 0 permits (per seconds), it means it's disabled. And internally I configure the bucket with a comical high limit rate.

You can see the code code bellow

```
    public void configure(int permitsPerSecond) {
        if (permitsPerSecond > 0) {
            // Enable rate limit with bucker4j
            Refill refill = Refill.intervally(permitsPerSecond, Duration.ofSeconds(1L));
            Bandwidth currentLimit = Bandwidth.classic(permitsPerSecond, refill);
            BucketConfiguration currentConfiguration =  BucketConfiguration.builder().
                    addLimit(currentLimit).
                    build();
            bucket.replaceConfiguration(currentConfiguration, TokensInheritanceStrategy.RESET);
        } else {
            // Disable rate limit with ludicrous high rate
            BucketConfiguration currentConfiguration =  BucketConfiguration.builder().
                    addLimit(Bandwidth.simple(999_999_999_999L, Duration.ofSeconds(1))).
                    build();
            bucket.replaceConfiguration(DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION,
                    TokensInheritanceStrategy.RESET);
        }
    }

    public boolean allowExecution() {
        return bucket.tryConsume(1L);
    }
```

I tried searching documentacion and code, expected a method like bucket.enable(boolean) and bucket.getLimit().getCapacty(), but no luck

Is there another way I can disable dinamically the bucket ?
Also, can I access the current capacity of the bucket from the Bucket class ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bucket4j does not provide direct ability to disable limits. So you need to find some trick that will behave aproximattely in desired way.

Fo example, you can reconfigure(via **replaceConfiguration**) the bucket with extremelly huge limit each time when you need to disbale limit. Bellow is example of effectivelly infinite limit that is enough for usual cases:

```
 BucketConfiguration infiniteConfiguration =  BucketConfiguration.builder().
                addLimit(Bandwidth.simple(Long.MAX_VALUE, Duration.ofNanos(Long.MAX_VALUE)).
                build();
```

Then each time when you need to activate limits again, you should to reconfigure bucket again with regular configuration.

Comment: Yep, that was my understanding. Thanks !